# Uitabbarcontroller in a UIViewController not in the appdelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

How do I integrate a `UITabbarcontroller` in a `UIViewController` class not in the app delegate? I was suppose to make a login view and after it the `UITabBarController` appears which was created in a `UIViewController` class? Can anyone suggest what needs to be done? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still put the `UITabBarController` in the App Delegate, when the login is done, just tell the app delegate, and switch the them:

> self.window.rootViewController=tabBarController;

Comment: You don't need code, you need to understand. Have two IBOUtlets in your AppDelegate. One for your login UIViewController and another for your UITabBarController. In the beginning, put your login UIViewController has your rootViewController, when you are done with it, just switch the rootViewController for your UITabBarController.

Comment: A UITabBarcontroller can only be the rootViewController, Apple do not allow you to use a tabBarController as a child of any other controller. Therefore, your first option is to switch as Jacky Boy says, a second option might be having the login view as a child (modal or otherwise) to the tabBarController.

Answer (score -2):

if your Application is Navigation Based App, then Create TabBarController(with ViewControllers how many you want to add) and add it on Navigation Controller, like this

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [Utility configureMessagesTabBArController];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
[tabBarController release];
```

here is **configureMessagesTabBArController** Method from Utility class

```
+(UITabBarController *)configureMessagesTabBArController
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    AktuellesViewController *aktuelles_Controller = [[AktuellesViewController alloc]init];
    TermineViewController *termine_Controller = [[TermineViewController alloc]init];
    TopTenViewController *topTen_Controller = [[TopTenViewController alloc]init];
    MediathekViewController *mediathek_Controller = [[MediathekViewController alloc]init];
    KontaktViewController *kontakt_Controller = [[KontaktViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:aktuelles_Controller];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:termine_Controller];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:topTen_Controller];
    UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mediathek_Controller];
    UINavigationController *nav5 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:kontakt_Controller];

    nav1.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nav2.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nav3.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nav4.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nav5.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5,nil]];

    [nav1 release];
    [nav2 release];
    [nav3 release];
    [nav4 release];
    [nav5 release];

    [aktuelles_Controller release];
    [termine_Controller release];
    [topTen_Controller release];
    [mediathek_Controller release];
    [kontakt_Controller release];

    return tabBarController;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, the above does not answer the original question. Secondly the text does not accurately say what the code does. The code adds the navigation controllers on to the tabs not the other way around.